# PK - быть или не быть? Вот в чем вопрос!

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня такой вопрос: обязательно ли нужен Primary Key если он нигде не используется? Например есть таблицы `articles(id, name)` и `tags(id, name)`, а в таблице `article_tags(article_id, tag_id)` идет связь. Так вот надо ли добавлять в эту таблицу столбец `id` просто чтобы был PK? Потому что в логике он никогда не будет использоваться.

Comment: обычно при использовании различных фреймворков со своим ORM они требуют наличия отдельного столбца с ключом. Если лично вам не нужен таковой, то сделайте составной первичный ключ по двум столбцам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первичный ключ в таблице обязан быть. Потому что если к записи в таблице невозможно обратится уникально то и работать с такой записью в одиночку невозможно. Кроме того в результате ошибок в программе могут появляться полностью одинаковые записи. НО нигде не говорится, что PK должен быть именно ID.

В таких таблицах, как ваша, отдельный id в качестве уникального ключа даже вреден, он не мешает создать две записи с одинаковыми article_id, tag_id. Поэтому в таких таблицах необходимо использовать составной первичный ключ из обоих колонок.

```
create table article_tags(
    article_id int not null,
    tag_id int not null,
    primary key (article_id, tag_id)
)
```

Comment: остается добавить, что при необходимости задания ID как первичного ключа, следует добавлять и уникальный индекс для исключения дублирования строк.